# Sending image attachment php

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I created an image with php imagecreate and I want to send it through e-mail with PHPMailer, but I don't understand which method I have to use and how

```
include 'Barcode39.php';
include 'PHPMailer.php';

$bar = new Barcode39('10127');

$bar->barcode_text_size = 10; 
$bar->barcode_bar_thick = 10; 
$bar->barcode_bar_thin = 5; 

$bar_img = $bar->draw();
$bar_size[0] = imagesx($bar_img);
$bar_size[1] = imagesy($bar_img);

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('biglietto.jpg');

imagecopymerge($im, $bar_img, 10, 9, 0, 0, $bar_size[0], $bar_size[1], 100);

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From = 'myemail@email.com';
$email->Body = 'my email';
$email->AddAddress( 'myemail@email.com' );

$email->addAttachment($im??);
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

> addAttachment(string  $path, string  $name = '', string  $encoding = 'base64', string  $type = '', string  $disposition = 'attachment') : boolean

Just provide string path to your file and you will be good.

Comment: The file that I want to attach is that $im created with imagecreate. Which is the path?

Comment: I believe you need to use function like _imagejpeg_ to save your image link ($im) to specific file.